# Using SSH to run command on remote server, but having trouble with quotes

Tags: bash, postgresql, ssh

## Problem

So I am trying to run a query against a postgres database over SSH. My command looks like this:

```
ssh myserver.com sudo -u postgres psql -t -A -F"," -d web_user -c "'SELECT reltuples::BIGINT as estimate, relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid in ('user_1.info'::regclass, 'user_1.addresses'::regclass) ;'"
```

But I am having trouble with the quotes being passed in the query. Here is the query pulled out of the command above:

```
"'SELECT reltuples::BIGINT as estimate, relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid in ('user_1.info'::regclass, 'user_1.addresses'::regclass) ;'"
```

From what I understand, the outer double quotes are being stripped out first, so the string becomes:

```
'SELECT reltuples::BIGINT as estimate, relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid in ('user_1.info'::regclass, 'user_1.addresses'::regclass) ;'
```

Now we have two pairs of single quotes (the outer pair wrapping the entire query string, and an inner pair wrapping the schema names in my query (e.g.  `'user_1.addresses'::regclass`). Unfortunately, those single quotes around the schema name are required by postgres, so I can't remove them or replace with double quotes.

Here's the problem, the second time the quotes are removed (by SSH I guess?), the query is invalidated because the single quotes around the schema names are removed :

`SELECT reltuples::BIGINT as estimate, relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid in (user_1.info::regclass, user_1.addresses::regclass) ;`

So instead of `'user_1.info'::regclass`, which is completely valid to postgres, we get this: `user_1.info::regclass`

---

## What I Tried

I tried escaping the  single quotes in the schema name (see: `\'user_1.addresses\'::regclass`):

```
ssh myserver.com sudo -u postgres psql -t -A -F"," -d web_user -c "'SELECT reltuples::BIGINT as estimate, relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid in (\'user_1.info\'::regclass, \'user_1.addresses\'::regclass) ;'"
```

I also tried running the entire command from a file, and that worked, but I am trying to run this command inline. From what I can tell, this is an issue with how the quotes are being stripped (first all double quotes, then all single quotes), and I haven't been able to find a solution.

Could someone please help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use escaped single quotes inside single quotes in shell.

Better use here-doc and avoid escaping issues:

```
ssh -t -t myserver.com sudo -u postgres psql -t -A -F"," -d web_user -c<<'EOF'
SELECT reltuples::BIGINT as estimate, relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid in ('user_1.info'::regclass, 'user_1.addresses'::regclass) ;
exit
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but it's like psql doesn't recognize the heredoc as an argument. Here's the output: `psql: option requires an argument -- 'c'`

Comment: You can use `$''` for ansi c escapes though and can escape single quotes in that.

Comment: Thanks @123, would you mind posting the full example?

Comment: @foxygen In you what i tried bit just put a `$` before the first quote and leave the inner ones escaped.

Comment: @foxygen: Try removing `-c` by using `ssh -t -t myserver.com sudo -u postgres psql -t -A -F"," -d web_user <<'EOF` as first line